# Setting a value to a variable from another class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I'm having a Windows Forms application with a combobox. I added items to the combobox (for example, 1,2,3,4). If I select an item in the combobox SelectedIndex should be returned to the variable in another class.

```
class Form1
{
    private void Combobox1_SelecetedIndexChanged(object sender,eventArgs e)
    {
        combobox1.selecetdeIndex ; //I will get the selected index.
        //If the selected index is changed then the currentValue in the AnotherClass should be 
        //changed.
    }
}

Class AnotherClass
{
    private int currentValue;
    //There are some methods which depends on currentValue.
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [call variable from another form c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928071/call-variable-from-another-form-c)

Comment: class Form1
{
 private void Combobox1_SelecetedIndexChanged(object sender,eventArgs e)
{
//i will get the selected index
 
}

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines: (pseudocode)

```
class SomeClass
{

  public int comboindex
  {
    get; set;
  }

}

SomeClass c = new SomeClass();

c.comboindex = mycombo.selectedindex;
```

Answer (score 2):

In [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), I guess the easiest approach is to handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, and inside the event handler, set the variable you want to set from there.

So the eventhandler would be like this:

```
private void MyComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
    instanceOfMyOtherClass.VariableInOtherClass = ComboBox1.SelectedItem;
}
```

Not much magic to get this done automatically in Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Raise an event from the form that the other class subscribes to?